# Keep child div on the bottom of parent div

Tags: html, css

I need to keep the `subfooter` div on the bottom of `childbox` div like a footer.Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsakD/1694/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
    .parentbox {
     width:500px;
     height:400px;
     border-style:solid;
     text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    }

    .parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
     content: ' ';
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
     height: 100%;
    }

    .childbox {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;          /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
     padding: 5px;
     border: 2px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
        <div id="subfooter">
        keep on bottom of box
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consult [mcve]. You need to include the relevant code **in** the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use following css:

```
.parentbox:before {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.childbox {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Currently you have set `vertical-align: middle` in your css causing your child element to appear in middle of screen.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {margin: 0;}
.parentbox {
  width:500px;
  height:100vh;
  border-style:solid;

  text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
}

.parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
  height: 100%;
}

.childbox {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;          /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
  <div class="childbox">
    I shall be in the bottom of parentbox regardless of its size!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you ... I actually managed a hack for the same, though not the correct way but i managed

Answer (score 0):

As per CSS specification, the parent must be set to `position: relative` and the child can be set to `position: absolute` or `fixed`

The modified fiddle for your amusement, know that the answer to this question can be found pretty much anywhere both on this website and the internet. Positioning, that's the word.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VsakD/1692/)

Also, a nice link about an article on positioning, might be helpful.
[Positioning](http://it.learnlayout.com/position.html)

Answer (score 0):

here maybe it help.

```css
html,body{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;}

.parentbox{
background:#ccc;
height:100%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;}

.childbox{
align-self:flex-end;
background:#999;}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
        I shall be in the middle of parentbox regardless of its size!
    </div>
</div>
```

it has many ways to answer.

1. position absolute, and set bottom to 0.
2. display flex and set align items or align self

you need to read more about css.
wish it help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the pseudo element for that just add position styling and there you go.

```css
.parentbox {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border-style:solid;
    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    position: relative;
}

.childbox {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
  <div class="childbox">
    I shall be in the middle of parentbox regardless of its size!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer, Through `CSS` itself you can achieve this.

```css
.parentbox{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #990000;
  position: relative;
}
.childbox{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
        I shall be in the middle of parentbox regardless of its size!
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it once..

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
        I shall be in the middle of parentbox regardless of its size!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parentbox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.childbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 12% !important;
}
```

I hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

```
.parentbox {
    position:relative;
}
.childbox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

There are many method to solute your requirement.Hope it can give you some tip