# Keep child div on the bottom of div box

Tags: html, css

I need to keep the subfooter div on the bottom of childbox div like a footer.Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsakD/1694/)

```
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
        <div id="subfooter">
        keep on bottom of box
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
<style>
.parentbox {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border-style:solid;

    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
}

.parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.childbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;          /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height:40%
}
</style>
```

And also need to keep the text 'keep on bottom of box' vertical align

Comment: What about this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438130/keep-child-div-on-the-bottom-of-parent-div/41438170#41438170) that you asked today?

Answer (score 0):

try this jsfilddle i assume that's which you want to do

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentbox">
<div class="childbox">
    <div id="subfooter">
    <div class = "footer">
    keep on bottom of box
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .parentbox {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border-style:solid;

    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
}

.parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.childbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;          /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height:40%
}
.footer {
    padding-top: 145px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2L6yjckz/

Answer (score 0):

**Just try it once.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
        <div id="subfooter">
        keep on bottom of box
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parentbox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.childbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 12% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and would [this](https://jsfiddle.net/16nu5rwm/) be anything close to what you are looking for?

All I've done is added

```
position: absolute;
```

To the .parentbox, and

```
position: absolute; bottom: 0;
```

To the .childbox

Hope this helps.